# In R, can the original time series impact forecast results for a subset time series?

Tags: r, forecasting

I did a forecast in R of a stl fit to a subset of time series data using the code below. The only difference between Scenario 1 & 2 is that I mistakenly set both the original time series and subset time series to `start=c(2015,12)` in Scenarios 2. The forecast results for the two scenarios is different. Both Scenarios have the same start date for the subset data that is used in the forecast. I do not understand why the original time series start date impacts the forecast results.

```
# Scenario 1    

ts.vision = ts(data=vision$ADJ_ILR, frequency = 12,start=c(2015,1), end=c(2017,12))                             
ts.vision.sub <- window(ts.vision, start=c(2015, 12))                               
ts.vision.fit <- stl(ts.vision.sub, t.window=15, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)                              
forecast(ts.vision.fit, h=12)


# Scenario 2    

ts.vision = ts(data=vision$ADJ_ILR, frequency = 12,start=c(2015,12), end=c(2017,12))                                
ts.vision.sub <- window(ts.vision, start=c(2015, 12))                               
ts.vision.fit <- stl(ts.vision.sub, t.window=15, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)                              
forecast(ts.vision.fit, h=12)
```

Here is a similar situation where I have re-written the two scenarios using the nottem dataset available on base R:
    # Scenario 1
    ts.nottem = ts(nottem, frequency = 12,start=c(1920,1), end=c(1939,12))
    ts.nottem.sub <- window(ts.nottem, start=c(1937, 12))
    ts.nottem.fit <- stl(ts.nottem.sub, t.window=15, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)
    forecast(ts.nottem.fit, h=12)

```
#Scenario 2
ts.nottem = ts(nottem, frequency = 12,start=c(1937,12), end=c(1939,12))
ts.nottem.sub <- window(ts.nottem, start=c(1937, 12))   
ts.nottem.fit <- stl(ts.nottem.sub, t.window=15, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)      
forecast(ts.nottem.fit, h=12)
```

I do not understand why the forecast results are different even though the subset time series data is the same between Scenario 1 & 2.

Comment: You might want to provide some context for the question. Which technology/environment is this referring to?

Comment: Can you replicate this question using one of the datasets available in base R (e.g. nottem)? easier to answer with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Here is Scenario 1 & 2 re-written to use nottem dataset available in base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your example with some built in data

```
library(forecast)
ts.1 <- ts(data=nottem[1:36], frequency = 12, start=c(2015,1), end=c(2017,12))                             
ts.1.sub <- window(ts.1, start=c(2015, 12))                               
ts.1.fit <- stl(ts.1.sub, t.window=15, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)                              
ts.1.fc <- forecast(ts.1.fit, h=12)

ts.2 <- ts(data=nottem[1:36], frequency = 12, start=c(2015,12), end=c(2017,12))                             
ts.2.sub <- window(ts.2, start=c(2015, 12))                               
ts.2.fit <- stl(ts.2.sub, t.window=15, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)                              
ts.2.fc <- forecast(ts.2.fit, h=12)

#all.equal(ts.1.fc, ts.2.fc) # NO!
```

I omit the long angry messages! What's happening? Take a look at the two subset objects:

```
head(ts.1.sub)
#>       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov  Dec
#> 2015                                                  39.8
#> 2016 44.2 39.8 45.1 47.0 54.1

head(ts.2.sub)

#>       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov  Dec
#> 2015                                                  40.6
#> 2016 40.8 44.4 46.7 54.1 58.5
```

They aren't the same, because in scenario 1 you are getting the 12th value through the 36th value in the original data, and in scenario 2 you are getting 1st through 25th values.